# iOS - where is the rootViewController loaded?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have created a blank project using the single view option on Xcode templates.

WHen this project loads, the rootViewController class is loaded, but I don't see on the app's delegate any line loading the rootViewController.

As I generally don't use interface builder and I create my controllers programmatically I ask: where is the rootViewController loaded and how do I change the app to load another viewController instead?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably in your MainWindow.xib, you define the first controller that you want to load, in your case it is `rootViewController`.

`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. This method is always known to be the first to be called when launching an application. Try to check here. The Main NIB File is set in Info.plist ( located in the target settings) so that you will already have a NIB loaded when your application delegate is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

It's loaded from the main interface builder file.
See your projects settings on what interface builder file is loaded, and then check what root controller it will load.

iOS loads your app -> then the Interface Builder (NIB) file specified in the settings for that app -> The nib loads a bunch of views/viewcontrollers etc

I hope you find it!